# Is leaving a company after 1 month ok?

Tags: resignation, startup, probation

A few weeks ago, I got a job at a 3 year old IT startup, specializing in consulting. I already know that it's not a place I want to stay for very long. Since I only started recently, I am still in the 3 months probation period.

When I applied, it was for a junior web developer job posting. On my first workday, I found out that both my title and day-to-day work had changed to something unrelated to web development.  I feel like I didn't get the job I applied for.

The work environment is horrible. It's an open office environment.  All the offices have a speaker and loud EDM music plays 9 a.m. to 6 p.m. every day. On Fridays, the music is so loud that it feels like working at a night club.
My colleagues seem to enjoy this atmosphere and deem it necessary to keep the atmosphere nice.  If no music is playing, people even ask "Why is it so quiet here? Are we the quietest office in town or what?"

I tried to ask whether the music can be lowered or turned off. Since it's a bluetooth speaker and everybody can control it, somebody started the music back up again after a few minutes of silence.  I also tried to cancel out the noise using headphones, but it doesn't work since I have the luck of sitting right next to the speaker.

Thirdly, I feel like I don't fit in socially. My colleagues come from a very different background, and I really have trouble adapting.

I want to quit this company and find another job, but I feel guilty about it too. I am currently still in the onboarding process and every day I get taught new things about the work. If I leave now I feel like I will throw all the work done by my colleagues into the water.  But the environment itself throws all of my work into the water, since I cannot concentrate properly at all.

What would you recommend me to do? Should I quit now or try to stay somehow? I am in my mid-twenties and therefore I have no idea how this incident will affect my future. I therefore really need your advice!

Comment: It's one month. You could just completely omit that job on your CV. Nobody will ask about one month...

Comment: You sound miserable there, and it doesn't sound like they are very accommodating. Start looking around for a new job before you quit. Don't feel guilty.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Yes, I could probably do that, but I also want to be honest about my experience. I don't want to "lie" that I never worked there.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I am kind of doing that already, and I feel ashamed about it because I'm doing it behind their backs.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Well, things can always change, probably, but I have made bad experiences of staying at a place for too long when the conditions were lacking before, so this time I want to be ahead on that.

Comment: If it is a bad fit, less harm for everyone to admit it after 1 month vs 1 year

Comment: @Audio-Engineer: it's not about hiding it, you want your CV to provide maximum signal to potential employers on why they should hire you, and that sort of inconsequential position just wastes space.

Comment: If I hadn't found out that the work environment was as you describe until the first day, I wouldn't have stayed for a month. I would probably have walked out for good before the end of day 1.

Comment: I used to work for a company that sounds exactly like that.  I stayed a year before I couldn't take it any more.

Comment: Probation periods is not only for the employee. What most companies don't realize is that _they_ are on probation, too.

Comment: Can't answer because question is closed but I was in a very similar situation - position not what I expected, culture not ok, 3 months I didn't have right to quit, but then I told them that I don't have money to pay them 3 months back and if they want me to sit there unmotivated until 3 months pass, then so be it... so they let me go. Before and after that I had long term jobs I was happy about. It was a lesson for me and a lesson for them.

Comment: In your case, at the very least you should ask for and be given a desk as far away as possible from the speakers. And get _good_ _closed_ on head noise cancelling headphones for maximum benefit. If that was the only problem.

Answer (score 46):

> Is leaving a company after 1 month ok?

Depends on the circumstances but in this case the answer is yes. There appears to be a cultural disconnect and these are very hard to fix. That's what probation is for: you can try it on for size and if it's not a fit there is a relatively easy way out.

It also means that you did NOT do your homework when interviewing. The purpose of the interview process is to determine if there is a good fit. This is clearly not a fit, so the interview process failed (for both parties). There is a lesson to be learned here: you don't want to end up in the same situation again. You should analyze your approach to interviewing and assess what needs to be changed. What question should you have asked, what data collected and what research done, that would have prevented this outcome in the first place.

Comment: This is a good answer, however I would not be so quick to put all the blame on the OP for the interview, I don't think I would have thought about asking "Will you change my title on the the first day?" or "Do you play loud EDM music at the workplace?".. This startup seems unusual in its ways of doing things

Comment: @Kaddath - an interview should be a two-way thing. OP should have asked all sorts of questions that he probably didn't, should have visited the 'office/workplace', which would have prompted at least one question. Simply having the job spec changed should be enough - and put on c.v. 'I stayed for only one month because the environment was intolerable and I was not allowed to do the job I applied for'. Reading that, as prospective employer, would encourage me to consider him as a candidate - one with principles.

Comment: @Tim yes I agree, the music thing could have been found out by the OP (even if in my case I would bother to visit the workplace only if I plan to stay quite long in the company or it's close to my place, but that is not precised in the question). But I think a honest recruiter should definetly ask "You don't mind working with music?". The title change, on the other side, couldn't really be foreseen. That's a two way blame IMO

Comment: Past a certain stage in the interview process, I always ask to go and see my actual workspace and meet my prospective coworkers. It’s important to see and experience the actual day to day environment you’re signing up for.

Comment: I agree with @Kaddath , even if you *do* visit the workplace, it's still very possible you overlook things that you will notice when working there for a full day. But that's exactly what a probation period is for isn't it? At least from the employee's perspective. Personally I've never visited the workplace during the interview phase, and I would never think about asking about music, unless maybe if it's a construction site. Perhaps this is location dependent?

Comment: @Kaddath blaming is pointless and not my intent. Instead I'm focusing on "what can be done differently next time to avoid repeating a mistake". The OP can only change their own actions. What the company does or not do is their own problem. More often than not candidates focus more on impressing the employer than asking detailed, hard, and potentially controversial questions. That's a very natural thing to do, but it's not the best way to approach an interview. Landing the wrong job is a worse outcome than not landing the job.

Comment: Regarding the music aspect, I personally ask about it during interviews because I like to listen to music as I work... on my headphones. Not all offices may be ok with that so I ask, but I would never expect to need to ask if others play music on loudspeakers, because I would never expect others to play music on loudspeakers in an office. That's an unusual feature that the hiring managers should have disclosed during the interview process.

Comment: @Kaddath "What's your office like? What's the culture like?" is a good place to start... Also, "What range of things do you work on? Is it pretty much the same stuff all the time, or are you learning new things every day? What does your day look like?" Just like no one's going to ask you if you're crazy, instead they ask about things like "one time you disagreed with someone" and try to figure out if you're a good fit from there.

Answer (score 18):

As has been noted in the comments, leaving is fine. Just don't mention it on your resume. Chances are people won't even ask what you did for the month or two gap on your resume but if they do you can just say that you took some much needed time off, wanted to pursue some personal projects, whatever.

Comment: Better stick to the truth. There is really no reason to lie about the gap if asked about it.

Comment: @Michael - there's no compelling reason to tell the truth, either. I've done exactly the same thing - left a month to the day after starting, because the job was dire (I'd jumped there due to redundancy, and something better came up). It doesn't exist on my CV because it could give the impression of flakiness, (although all my other jobs have lasted > 7y)

Comment: @SiHa: I’d also leave it out of the CV (simply because it doesn’t add any value) but if asked about it, I don’t see any way for the truth to hurt you. At the same time, lying could backfire if the interviewer/recruiter somehow found out about it in their background research or because they know people at your former short-term employment.

Comment: @Michael -Yeah, I suppose omission != lying. If directly asked, I'd probably fess up.

Comment: @Michael Ditching a job after 4-6 weeks would seriously make me consider dropping a candidate right there.  If you're looking for a reason.  Obviously the circumstances matter, but however it reflects on the employer, it doesn't look good from any angle on the candidate.

Answer (score 12):

When starting a new job you get *probation time*. This is mutual! At least in my country during probation (usually three month) both parties can terminate the employment agreement within one weeks notice (or even sooner if both agree).

Think of it not only as time where the company can evaluate you, but also the other way around. You are evaluating the workplace to see if it is a job you like!

The only reason to stay is, if it is a very good opportunity such that it completely outweighs the downsides and it is really difficult for you to get a similar chance at some other company. From what and how you tell the story, I doubt that this is the case. Hence it seems pretty clear to me what you should be doing.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

(Shrug ...) I think I'd do exactly the same thing.  "I prefer classical music, myself."  If you want to listen to music, that's what headphones are for.

You've obviously accidentally landed into "a *weird* situation," and no, you don't need to put up with it.  Just find the most-gracious way that you can think of to say to them: *"See ya!"*  Another good job will come along very soon enough.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, leaving a company after 1 month is ok.**

If you're going to quit, the sooner you do it the better. Nobody will notice or care about a one month "gap" in your CV. If you quit after such a short period of time then your justification is more believable. If you wait for six months then it starts to look like you are unreliable.

This particular employer lied to you about the job description and therefore does not even deserve the courtesy of being given notice. Unless you are desperate for income then I would quit immediately. There is no future at a company that has LIED to you and has a party atmosphere in the office. Best of luck to you.

Note: This is not legal advice.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving after one month is exactly what probabition is there for. Both you and the company are on probation, and the company failed.

Just follow the recommended steps: Find a new job, sign a legally binding contract, and then you give notice. You don't want to be without income if you can help it. (That's assuming the company isn't so bad that you want to leave *right now* even if it costs you money).